# How to inject ILogger into EFCore DbContext

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core

I have .net core app with EFCore db context:

```
public class MyappDbContext : DbContext
{
    private ILogger<MyappDbContext> _logger;

    public MyappDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyappDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
        // ???
    }
}
```

In startup class I registered context:

```
services.AddDbContext<MyappDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

How to inject into `MyappDbContext`, `ILogger` or `ILoggerFactory` (to create logger)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All you need to do is add a `ILoggerFactory` or `ILogger` parameter to the context constructor:

```
public class MyappDbContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly ILogger<MyappDbContext> _logger;

    public MyappDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyappDbContext> options,
        ILogger<MyappDbContext> logger)
        : base(options)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be sure though, you also have an empty constructor for EF database migrations to work.

Comment: Well OP would already have that problem so that's a different question really.

Comment: It works excellent.
In a meantime I had create IDbContextFactory. And migrations use IDbContextFactory to create my dbContext.

Comment: @DavidG ofcourse, i just think its a good mention because this is nr#1 made fault with and question asked on SO.

Comment: @JoelHarkes Hmm, it's far from being number 1 fault, it's not even in the top 1000 I would say!

Answer (score 1):

In case if you need to instantiate the dbcontext manually:

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public static readonly ILoggerFactory logFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder => builder.AddDebug());

    ....

    public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        ....
    }
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ....
    }
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly ILoggerFactory _loggerFactory;

    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options,
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        : base(options)
    {
        _loggerFactory = loggerFactory;
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseLoggerFactory(_loggerFactory);
        // optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
    }
}

// Somewhere else

var db = new MyDbContext(new DbContextOptions<MyDbContext>(), Startup.logFactory);
```

But I would recommend using DI instead:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
            services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default")).UseLoggerFactory(logFactory));
}
```